# Retrieve data from sql into specified place in text

Tags: bash, mysql, sql

I'm very new to sql and bash-scripting, but even so I've manage to make a sql-table with coming events. And I manage to make a Script deleting old events and export everything in the table to a textfile. And this is how that code looks..

```
#!bin/bash
mysql -uroot -pPass kalender -e "delete from event where datum < now()"
mysql -uroot -pPass kalender -e "select * from event" > textfile.txt
```

But how shall I do to make a specifik field in a text, like this..

Ex. 
The (date1) (artist1) will come to (place1) on (day1) at (time1)
The (date2) (artist2) will come to (place2) on (day2) at (time2)

Comment: For this type of output you do not even need the `bash`. Instead you can do the formatting in the select statement itself by not using `*` but acccesing the table columns directly, converting them to strings, concatening them and interspersing fixed text tokens where you need them.

Comment: Do you need more help with my suggested solution?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the columns of your table `event` are named as they are in the expected output you could do this:

```
mysql -uroot -pPass kalender -B  --disable-column-names -e "select concat('The ', date_format(date1, '%d.%m.%Y'), ' ', artist1, ' will come to place ', place1, ' on ', date_format(day1, '%W'), ' at ', date_format(time1, '%H:%i')) from event" > textfile.txt
```

Notes:

- Of course, you can change the formatting of the date and time fields as you wish. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp for a comprehensive list of formats.
- If `date1` , `day1`, and `time1` are actually referring to the same column, that's no problem at all. You just use the same column name for all formats and the format strings determine what is printed out.
- I added the options `-B` and `--disable-column-names` to suppress the normal formatting of the select statement.